# protractor 4.0.0 breaking changes affect access to vanilla webdriver

Tags: webdriver, protractor

In the changelog under the 4.0.0 breaking changes, states

> (d932ad7) chore(browser): rename protractor to browser and add a
>   protractor namespace (#3214)
>
> added wrapDriver method from the browser.ts and ExpectedConditions to
>   the protractor namespace imported selenium webdriver ActionSequence,
>   Key, promise, Command, and CommandName to the protractor namespace

How does this affect usage of vanilla Webdriver as described in [Protractor Syntax vs WebDriverJS Syntax](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/webdriver-vs-protractor.md)?